# Powershell - Find all users with password never expires

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell

I am looking to query AD via Powershell in order to see all user accounts within my forest who have their password set to never expire.

I found a few scripts online using a quick google search but none of them appear to work as expected. I then found the following on technet (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/finding_users_whose_password_never_expires%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) however when I run the line:

```
Search-ADAccount -PasswordNeverExpires | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
```

I only receive a very small number of results and I know that the list returned is missing a large number of users who I know have this option set.

Please can someone tell me what is incorrect with this script or what the reason for the small result set could be?

Comment: Try `Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties PasswordNeverExpires | select name,Pass
wordNeverExpires | Where-Object {$_.PasswordNeverExpires -like "True"} ` does that give you the same results as search-adaccount?

Comment: I'm wondering if it is permission to various OUs that is causing the issues

Comment: I am running the powershell as administrator with a domain admin account and I get the same results as before.

Comment: You shouldn't need to run it as administrator. Try not doing so

Comment: @DavidHirst Try this query: Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536))' compare the results with the other results you have. Maybe those other users you know about but don't show up have something else (like the wrong PSO) that causes their password to not expire.

Comment: Also, try this: (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))' -Properties msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed | ?{($_.'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed' -eq 0) -or ($_.'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed' -eq 9223372036854775807)})

Comment: Hi Eliad, I get no results for your first query but I do get a complete list like Arts with your second query. Thanks.

Comment: what about local users? Please point me how to do it for these accounts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use the below to and it works.

```
get-aduser -filter * -properties Name, PasswordNeverExpires | where { $_.passwordNeverExpires -eq "true" } | where {$_.enabled -eq "true"}
```

It searches against AD database to find user's with "PasswordNeverExpires" set to "True" then returns the results in the Powershell console.

edit for wording and wrong cmdlet and to add the below
To cleanup the results add this to the end of the above powershell code

```
| Format-Table -Property Name, PasswordNeverExpires -AutoSize
```

Comment: Hi Art, Thanks this appears to have worked, I have checked a number of the OUs I know have this option checked and they are now pulling through into the list.

Comment: I'd recommend condensing your where statement into a single where that handles both operations.

Comment: haha you know I never thought of doing that.  That powershell code was put together quickly some time ago and I never looked it back over for improvements.  Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: get-aduser -filter * -properties Name, PasswordNeverExpires | where { $_.passwordNeverExpires -eq "true" -and $_.enabled -eq "true"} | Format-Table -Property Name, PasswordNeverExpires -AutoSize

Answer (score 5):

You could use something like this:

```
Get-ADUser -filter { (PasswordNeverExpires -eq $true) -and (enabled -eq $true)} -searchbase "OU=,OU=,DC=,DC=" -Properties Surname,givenname, userprincipalName,PasswordNeverExpires| FT Name,ObjectClass,PasswordNeverExpires -A
```

Comment: Hi Sorcha, I receive the same number of users as the original line, yet there are users in AD with this property set that do not appear in the results

Comment: Be sure having the rights on the OUs you want to list. In the filter, you can add `surname -eq "<surname of one user don't appear>"`

Comment: As mentioned I have full access to all OUs in the domain. However even if I specifically target an OU with 5 users and run your script I only get back 1 user in the results. Even though all 5 users have the property set to true. This is very bizarre.

Comment: Upvoted for using -Filter in your Get-ADUser which will be much faster than returning all users and filtering in the pipeline

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm running on multi-domain env:

```
$domains = (Get-ADForest).domains
$Members = foreach ($domain in $domains) {
    Get-ADUser -server $domain -filter {PasswordNeverExpires -eq "TRUE"} -Properties PasswordNeverExpires | select name,samaccountname,PasswordNeverExpires,mail | Where-Object {$_.PasswordNeverExpires -like "True"} |Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\Never_Expire-$domain.csv" -NoTypeInformation }
```

For single domain:

```
Get-ADUser -filter {PasswordNeverExpires -eq "TRUE"} -Properties PasswordNeverExpires | select name,samaccountname,PasswordNeverExpires,mail | Where-Object {$_.PasswordNeverExpires -like "True"} |Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\Never_Expire.csv" -NoTypeInformation }
```